# Particlesystem bugged // Evee Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine

My Particle system is working fine but as soon as I try to render the animation all my particles get emitted at once.

Here is the particle distribution in the viewport as intended:

[image]

---

And this is what it looks like after rendering (it usually resets when I change the particle system settings but the glitch reappears after rendering)

[image]

but whenever I render the animation there's a hole in the prerendering of the particle movement and after stopping the render the particles all get emitted at once.

---

The timeline clearly shows that the particle system doesn't respond for at least 10 frames or so at the start of the animation although I set the starting frame of the particles to -100

[image]

[image]